# How can I make a condition for a variable?

Tags: opencart

I have a working GeoIP detection code on the 'product.tpl' page in Opencart.
How can I make a condition for a variable?
Example: if the "city"="London" then php echo "Your city is London".

```
<script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<div>Country: <span id="country"></span></div>
<div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
<div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>

<script>
   $.ajax({
   url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
   jsonpCallback: "callback",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function( location ) {
      $('#country').html(location.country_name);
      $('#state').html(location.state);
      $('#city').html(location.city);
    }
});     
</script>
```

Comment: What? this makes no sense you explained what your code does basically

Comment: Sorry.
This code is displayed the visitor Country,State and City datas based on IP address.
It's working corretly, but I need one more line under the <div> lines:
If the "City" = "London" then display a message "XXX", else display "YYY".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check City and insert message that you need.

For example

```
var text = '';

  if(location.city == 'London'){
    text = 'XXX';
  } else {
    text = 'YYY';
  }

  $('#city').parent().after('<p>' + text + '</p>');
```